# Laravel / AJAX Like Button Error: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: ajax, laravel, eloquent, facebook-like

I'm very new to Laravel, AJAX etc. I am a student working on a Twitter type project and this is my first stack question ever made. I've tried to look for answers but the code that my teacher has helped me with is very different from other examples. I'm pretty sure that my problem is with the unlike method inside of my "Tweet Controller"... Any help is greatly appreciated! Hopefully I have provided enough information and hopefully this can help others in the future :)

This is my error:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkxsd.png

```
POST http://localhost:8000/tweets/19/unlike 404 (Not Found)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (app.js:14253)
at settle (app.js:35706)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (app.js:14127)
```

This is my likes table / migration

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLikesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('tweet_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('likes');
}
}
```

This is my Tweet Controller

```
public function like($id){


     $like = Like::create([
         'user_id'=>auth()->id(),
         'tweet_id'=> $id

     ]);
     if($like){
         return json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));

     }
     return json_encode(array('status' => 'failed'));

 }

 public function unlike($id){
     $like = Like::delete([
         'user_id'=>auth()->id(),
         'tweet_id'=> $id

     ]);

    if($like){
        return json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));
    }
}
```

This is my Web Routes

```
Route::post('tweets/{tweet}/like', 'TweetController@like');
Route::delete('tweets/{tweet}/like', 'TweetController@unlike');
```

This is my Model

```
    public function likes(){
    return $this->hasMany(Like::class);
}

public function likedByCurrentUser(){
    $userId=auth()->id();

    //like boolean
    $like = $this->likes->first(function($v) use ($userId){
        //$v is a reference to the single like
        return $v->user_id == $userId;
    });

    //if the user has liked a post
    if($like){
       return true;
   }
   return false;

}
```

This is my Vue Component:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'likeButton',
    props: ['likeCount','hasLiked','tweetId','csrf'],

     mounted(){
         this.dataLikeCount = this.likeCount;
         this.dataHasLiked = this.hasLiked;
     },
        data(){
            return{
                dataLikeCount:0,
                dataHasLiked:false

            }
        },

        methods:{
            doLike(){
                var type='like';

                if(this.dataHasLiked){
                    type='unlike'
                }

                axios({
                    method:'POST',
                    url:'/tweets/' + this.tweetId + '/'+ type,
                    headers:{
                        'X-CSRFToken':this.csrf
                    },
                    json: true

                    }).then((response) => {
                        if(response.data.status == 'success'){
                            // response was successful (regardless of type)
                            return true
                            // if type is like
                                // add one to like count, set hasLiked to true
                                if(type == 'like'){
                                    this.dataLikeCount++
                                }
                            // if type is unlike
                                // deduct one from like count, set hasLiked to false
                                if(type =='unlike'){
                                    return false
                                    this.dataLikeCount--
                                }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
</script>

<template>
<div>
    <button type="submit"
    :class="{'btn btn-link':dataHasLiked}"
    @click="doLike">

          <i class="star"></i>
          Like {{ dataLikeCount }}

    </button>
</div>


</template>
```

Comment: can you share your browser debug console network

Comment: I edited my post. does that help or do you need more? Sorry, like I said, new to this. When you click on the error link, it shows unlike in the network tab and then a whole lot of things mentioning routing.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have a matching route for `unlike`.

Change

```
Route::delete('tweets/{tweet}/like', 'TweetController@unlike');
```

To

```
Route::delete('tweets/{tweet}/unlike', 'TweetController@unlike');
```

Answer (score 0):

As said by @DigitalDrifter you doesn't have route for unlike. so need to change that.

Your routes is like

```
Route::delete('tweets/{tweet}/unlike', 'TweetController@unlike');
```

So have to call this route with DELETE method using ajax. you have ajax call with post method.it will also give method not allowed error.

So change your web route,

From

```
 Route::delete('tweets/{tweet}/unlike', 'TweetController@unlike');
```

To

```
 Route::post('tweets/{tweet}/unlike', 'TweetController@unlike');
```

And change return response in your controller methods, It will look like below

Tweet Controller

```
public function like($id){


     $like = Like::create([
         'user_id'=>auth()->id(),
         'tweet_id'=> $id

     ]);
     if($like){
         return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);

     }
     return response()->json(['status' => 'failed']);

 }

 public function unlike($id){
     $like = Like::delete([
         'user_id'=>auth()->id(),
         'tweet_id'=> $id

     ]);

    if($like){
        return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps now!!

Comment: Oh ha I forgot to change the like to unlike. I've now got Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 405

Comment: Yes because your route is of delete method and you are calling that route with post ajax method

Comment: So either do seperate ajax call with delete method or   better I suggest change your route method to post

Comment: So if I change the route to post, I have to change my unlike controller method from $like = Like::delete     to  ? Sorry like I said I'm really new to this.

Comment: No no need to change the controller method just change the route it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately it has a: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500? Thank-you for your help by the way

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Route::delete('tweets/{tweet}/unlike', 'TweetController@unlike');
```